# Отображение постов на сайте django

Tags: html, css, python, django

Пишу веб сервис для вывода расписания врачей через удалённый доступ на экраны телевизоров. На скрине выложил, как выглядит блок расписания врачей. Блок добавляется через админ панель, всем блокам присвоен единый класс, вопрос вот в чем, как сделать чтобы страничка не скроллилась, а блоки перемещались вправо?

[image: Блоки врачей]

То есть чтобы врач 4 , которого не видно на скрине, автоматически помещался рядом с врачом 1

Comment: смотрите и правьте шаблон (html) для данной страницы, чтобы у вас на странице столбики из контента формировались

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [1,2,3,4] # массив с врачами
N = 3 # К-во записей в одной колонке
step = len(data)/N
if int(steps) != steps:
    step = int(steps)+1
else:
    step = int(steps)

a = []
for i in range(0, N):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(0, step):
        if i+N*j < len(data):
            a[i].append(data[i+N*j])

print(a)
```

Алгоритм не идеален, возможны ошибки.
В случае с таким же к-вом данных, как у вас в примере, выведет `[[1, 4], [2], [3]]` - на странице в первой "строке" будет 1и4 записи, во второй - 2, в третьей - 3.

Как это применить в шаблоне, думаю, пояснения не требует.

Можно переписать алгоритм для разбития по столбикам, но со способом выше, имхо, проще.